# Was Bill Murray actually "in the room" with the 2016 Ghostbusters?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, ghostbusters-2016

Watching the new (2016) Ghostbusters movie, it struck me that the scene with Bill Murray was shot in a very odd manner, with no scenes where he actually interacts directly with the cast, other than the initial shot where he walks into the room (which could very easily be a [split-screen shot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0z1F3qiN6E)). It's always over his shoulder looking at them, with his hat blocking his face, or where the camera is looking directly at him. Occasionally you'll see one of the actresses enter the frame in the reaction shots, but you never *actually* quite see their faces, only their hands and arms.

The actresses made a big point in an interview about how proud they were to have been "[in a room with Bill Murray](http://bigstory.ap.org/article/f26ab57608114097a2f5d73decd656f0/qa-laughing-along-wickedly-funny-ghostbusters)", **but *were they really in the room with him during this scene?***

Comment: Is there any actual evidence that they *weren't* in the room with him?  Rumours that Mr Murray is some sort of recluse or he was liable to be difficult about being together with a new generation of Ghostbuster girls?  Anything?  Sure, I get that it's *possible* these scenes were all shot separately, but it's also *possible* they were shot together.  It would be more effort and more time (and more billable hours for crew, stunt doubles, and post-production) to shoot Mr Murray apart from the new girls, so why would they have done this?

Comment: @Steve-O - Given his reluctance to do the cameo (they had to threaten to sue him),  my personal guess is that he negotiated them down to a single day of filming against a greenscreen and that they edited it together afterwards.

Comment: @Steve-O - Also, have you watched the clip? It's *clearly* a stand-in in all the reverse-angle shots.

Comment: Is this getting downvotes because it's about Ghostbusters?

Comment: @Valorum what grounds would they have to sue him for refusing to do a cameo?!?

Comment: @Moo - we may never know. [One of the leaked emails](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/12/12/shocking-new-reveals-from-sony-hack-j-law-pitt-clooney-and-comparing-fincher-to-hitler.html) from Sony said that they were willing to go to "***Aggressive litigation***" if he refused to do a cameo and positively promote Ghostbusters (e.g. say nice things about it, regardless of his personal opinions). My understanding is that most Hollywood contracts contain clauses guaranteeing that actors will at least cameo in sequels and will say nice things about those films, even if they aren't the star

Comment: <tinfoil hat>I'd wager given that if it's true, then it would be a touchy subject, therefore, why would "they" release any information about it? </tinfoil hat>

Comment: The part from 0:43 to 0:49 in your clip, where Bill Murray uses his stick to push something they're holding, that doesn't do it for you?

Comment: @AakashM - isn't it odd that you can't actually see their faces, only their arms and backs. Then when it cuts to the reverse-angle, his face is hidden by the hat.

Comment: I find this question absolutely interesting and worthy, and got me very curious (though I haven't seen the new ghostbusters, and generally not into to conspiracy theories), but I don't think this is the right site for it. Wouldn't you get better answers on Movies or Skeptics?

Comment: Slight distinction: “identifying aggressive litigation counsel” is actually not the same as “aggressively litigating.” What Sony was trying to hide: “In order to more fully evaluate our position if Bill Murray again declines to engage on ‘Ghostbusters’, AG requested that we identify ‘aggressive’ litigation counsel with whom we can consult to evaluate our alternatives and strategize. [Harkening back to his prior employer, of course, raised the name of David Boies.] Personally, while I’m fine with aggressive, I think we are in much worse shape if this goes public so seems to me we should…

Comment: …look for someone who isn’t seeking the spotlight.”

Comment: Sony also confirmed they knew they were making a film that was not Ghostbusters but were secretly trying to find ways to make any connection: Agree that everyone is way too nervous about how this issue and how we. present it but it's isn't a sequel to the 80s movies and it is gonna be totally original with completely different characters and our job is to find a clever way to connect the movie to the original franchise so that we can use all the assets and everything that is great about the original franchise,”

Answer (score 15):

Unless you imagine that the entire cast is just *lying*, then yes.

> AP: What was it like having Bill Murray there?
>
> Jones: He brought beast mode.
>
> McCarthy: It was a little surreal.
>
> McKinnon: I didn't speak. I was like, 'I'm in a room with Bill Murray. What strange sequence of events has taken place that's brought me in the same room as Bill Murray?'
>
> Jones: My favorite scene was when (McCarthy's character) was arguing with Bill, and I'm like, 'That's right! You tell him!' And then I realized, 'Oh, you're not watching a movie.'

Bill Murray was "there", and was "in the same room", and one actress was "watching" another actress "argue with Bill". I don't see any possible way to interpret this other than they were in the room with Bill Murray doing a scene.

Comment: Yeah, if that's the case though, then why aren't there any scenes in the film that show him and them in the same room, aside from a 2 second pan that appears to be a split-screen? Something doesn't add up. Note that if you read the interview carefully there areally two claims here, one that they met Bill Murray and the other that her favourite scene **in the film** is the scene with the argument. At no point does she claim that the filming happened at the same time.

Comment: Also, you've quoted from the interview in my original question. I was hoping for some more proof than a PR puff-piece.

Comment: I know this is SFF and not Skeptics, but still, this doesn't seem like "proof", as it relies in likely-biased witness testimony with plausible motive to lie even if it didn't happen.

Comment: As a minimum, they could have been talking about a read-through rather than the actual filming.

Comment: It was a little surreal because they thought they would film with Murray in the room but instead they all green screened it with Murray Zoom-meeting in his part while they talked to a stand-in in a green suit. Murray was beast mode because he flew in, filmed his parts in isolation for 30 minutes then flew back out.